vite Pre-transform error. Does the file exist
I have a capacitor project with a file structure which looks like this:
.
└── my-app/
    ├── vite.config.ts
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    └── src/
        ├── html/
        │   └── index.html
        ├── js/
        │   ├── custom-header.js
        │   ├── main.js
        │   └── ..
        ├── css/
        │   └── style.css
        └── assets

The vite.config.ts looks like this:
//.. necessary imports..
export default defineConfig({
  root: './src/html',
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    minify: false,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions:{
      input:{
      //Add the files needed for the application because they are required later when building the app
      main: resolve(__dirname,'src/html/index.html'),      
      nested: resolve(__dirname,'src/html/info.html'),
      },
    },
  },
});

My index.html is not directly in the src but I put it in the folder named html. and it looks like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    //Header Infos
    <body>
    <custom-navbar>
    </custom-navbar>
    
    <div class="m-4">
      <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="5" cols="33" class="description-input" placeholder="Describe your image"></textarea>
      <br/><button class="button mt-4" id="save">Save Image</button>
      <my-photos></my-photos>
    </div>
    
    <script src="../js/main.js" type="module"></script>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>

But vite says:
[vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to load url /js/main.js (resolved id: /js/photo-list.js). Does the file exist?

(For simplicity I didn't add the other js files which are not imported aswell)
I tried to put the root as root: './src/html', and point to the js file from the html with:"../js/main.js". But It kind of doesn't see it. Can someone explain what is happening and how to correct it? Thanks
